# Splitting text file using indexing

Tags: python-2.7

I have a file example

```
a=1,2,3,4ptr
b=5,6,7,5ptr
c=9,10,11float
```

how to split this using indexing and store into dictionary and seperate the ptr from float so that all ptr should be in a ptr file and float in a float file. 
output should be like `{'a':['1','2','3','4ptr']}`

Comment: Post what you've tried so far. We start from existing code here.

Comment: There is a small format corruption here, is it possible for you to separate the type part while getting file from the source? Otherwise you will have to write few lines more or a nice regexp.

Comment: after splitting the file we have to seperate by checking the last index

Comment: Post the required output and the code you have tried to achieve it

Answer (score 1):

Maybe these lines codes,

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-


def convert_file(file_path):
    f = open(file_path, "rb")
    result = {}
    for line in f.xreadlines():
        line = line.replace("\n", "")
        result[line.split("=")[0]] = line.split("=")[1].split(",")
    return result


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print convert_file("./sb.txt")
```